# Unable to send data to google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

[image]I have dimension and metric group hits in reports. could anybody help me to send data to google analytics to populate data in the report?

```
Reactga.ga("send", "Hits","My Account","Search", { 'AccountName2': value, 'MemberName5':company_name, 'UserName6':firstName });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Reactga.ga("send", "Hits","My Account","Search", {
      'AccountName2':  value,
      'MemberName5':company_name,
      'UserName6':firstName
    });

these are my dimension but these are not populating

Comment: And how long did you wait?   It can take 24 -48 hours for standard reports to complete processing